# Angular promise chaining with passed parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

In my Angular application I am trying call a series of functions, each one returning a value which becomes the input for the next one. Conceptually it is something like this:

```
$scope.createPanel = function() {
   var primer3_parameter_id = primer3FromDesignSetting($scope.selector.designSetting);
   var panel = getPanelData(primer3_parameter_id);

   Restangular.all('batches').post(panel).then(function(batch) {
      createBatchDetailRows(batch);   
   });
};
```

I have discovered this will not work, due  to async nature of the remote calls: they return a promise rather than an actual result.

I assume I need to do something like this:

```
$scope.createPanel = function() {
  primer3FromDesignSetting($scope.selector.designSetting)
     .then(getPanelData(primer3_parameter_id))
     .then(postPanel(panel))    // the Restangular call wrapped into a new function
     .then(createBatchDetailRows(batch))
     .catch(function(err) {
           // error handler
     }
 };

 function primer3FromDesignSetting(designSetting) {
     var primer3Parameter = _.clone(Restangular.stripRestangular(designSetting));
     primer3Parameter = _.omit(primer3Parameter,panelFields);
     delete primer3Parameter.id;
     Restangular.all('primer3_parameters').post(primer3Parameter).then(function(newPrimer3Parameter) 
     {
         return newPrimer3Parameter.id;
     }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
     });
  }

$scope.createPanel();
```

But I can't quite get my head around the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to chain an async call, then return a promise (notice the return value).  The resolution of that promise will be passed as an argument to the next then handler (in this case, it is newPrimer3Parameter.id):

```
 function primer3FromDesignSetting(designSetting) {
     var primer3Parameter = _.clone(Restangular.stripRestangular(designSetting));
     primer3Parameter = _.omit(primer3Parameter,panelFields);
     delete primer3Parameter.id;
     return Restangular.all('primer3_parameters').post(primer3Parameter).then(function(newPrimer3Parameter) 
     {
         return newPrimer3Parameter.id;
     }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each promise will return a successHandler and error handler. So the structure would be something like this:

```
 primer3FromDesignSetting($scope.selector.designSetting)//Asynchronous task that returns a promise
    .then(SuccessHandler1,ErrorHandler1) //Promise 1 - ErrorHandler optional
    .then(SuccessHandler2,ErrorHandler2) //Promise 2 - ErrorHandler optional
    .then(SuccessHandler3, ErrorHandler3) //Promise 3 - ErrorHandler optional
```

Here's how the promises would work(According to google employees Shyam Sheshadri (formerly of google) and Brad Green (Angular Team)):

1. Each asynchronous task will return a promise object.
2. **Each promise object will have a *then* function that can take two arguments, a success
   handler and an error handler.**
3. The success or the error handler in the *then* function will be called only once, after
   the asynchronous task finishes.
4. The *then* function will also return a promise, to allow chaining multiple calls.
5. **Each handler (success or error) can return a value, which will be passed to the next
   function in the chain of promises.**
6. If a handler returns a promise (makes another asynchronous request), then the next
   handler (success or error) will be called only after that request is finished.